# JavaFX How do you bind an animation to a certain value?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, binding

I have made an application with JavaFX, where you have a picture with animated stuff in it, based on certain values in the app. The only problem I have: I don't really know, how to bind the values to the animations, so the animations move, based on the value put in. For example: if the value is 10, the animation should move fast. If the value is 1 the animation should move slow. Here is the code for the animation (it is smoke, coming out of a house):

```
    smoke = new Image(HydroControl.class.getResource("/imgs/smoke.png").toExternalForm());
    smokeView = new ImageView(smoke);
    smokeView.setX(-190);
    smokeView.setY(60);

    Path path3 = new Path();
    path3.getElements().add(new MoveTo(1,-60));
    path3.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    PathTransition pathTransition3 = new PathTransition();
    pathTransition3.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
    pathTransition3.setPath(path3);
    pathTransition3.setNode(smokeView);
    pathTransition3.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    pathTransition3.setAutoReverse(true);
    pathTransition3.play();
```

Here is the code with the values:

```
public class PresentationModel {
private final DoubleProperty waterValue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
private final DoubleProperty powerValue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
private final BooleanProperty isOnValue = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

public double getWaterValue() {
    return waterValue.get();
}

public DoubleProperty waterValueProperty() {
    return waterValue;
}

public void setWaterValue(double waterValue) {
    this.waterValue.set(waterValue);
}

public double getPowerValue() {
    return powerValue.get();
}

public DoubleProperty powerValueProperty() {
    return powerValue;
}

public void setPowerValue(double powerValue) {
    this.powerValue.set(powerValue);
}

public boolean isIsOnValue() {
    return isOnValue.get();
}

public BooleanProperty isOnValueProperty() {
    return isOnValue;
}

public void setIsOnValue(boolean isOnValue) {
    this.isOnValue.set(isOnValue);
}
}
```

I would be really glad if you could help me. Thank you.

Comment: Try to make your animation duration (`pathTransition3.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));`) dependant of your application value.

Comment: Set (or bind) the `rate` property of your animation to a value calculated from the input. The higher the rate, the faster the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the properties of your transition to the values of your model with a calculation from the [`Bindings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) class. For example:

```
pathTransition3.durationProperty().bind(Bindings.multiply(Bindings.multiply(model.powerProperty(), model.waterValueProperty()), 500d));

model.isOnValueProperty().addListener((v, o, n) -> {
    if (n) {     
      pathTransition3.play(); 
    } else { 
      pathTransition3.pause(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Somehow I'm not able to use pathTransition3 even though it's in the same class.